# Trying to get property of non-object after passing an array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a `users` table and a `photos` table. The photos table has been linked to the users table (and some other tables) through imageable_id and imageable_type. Everything's working fine for that.

Now I wanted to return an array to a view that contains: user's name, user's email, user's desc, and user's image path (which is from the photos table).

What I did was I created an `array` that holds a collection of arrays from each user's data, and then passed that `array` to the view:

```
$user_admins = array();

    $admin_id = 1;
    $admins = User::where('role_id', $admin_id)->orderBy('name', 'asc')->get();

    foreach($admins as $admin)
    {

        $photo = Photo::where('imageable_id', $admin->id)->where('imageable_type', 'App\User')->first();

        $admin_data = array('name'=>$admin->name, 'email'=>$admin->email, 'desc'=>$admin->desc, 'path'=>$photo->path);
        array_push($user_admins, $admin_data);
    }

    // return $user_admins;

    //Return View
    return view('pages/home_admin', compact('user_admins'));
```

However on the view page, I get a `Trying to get property of non-object` that points out to my:

```
<h5 class="card-title">{!!$admin->name!!}</h5>
```

How can I access those user's data on my view?

Thanks a lot!

## Update

I also tried:

```
foreach($admins as $admin)
    {

        $admin_data['name'] = $admin['name'];
        $admin_data['email'] = $admin['email'];
        $admin_data['desc'] = $admin['desc'];

        $photo = Photo::where('imageable_id', $admin->id)->where('imageable_type', 'App\User')->first();
        $admin_data['path'] = $photo['path'];

        // $admin_data = array('name'=>$admin->name, 'email'=>$admin->email, 'desc'=>$admin->desc, 'path'=>$photo->path);
        array_push($user_admins, $admin_data);
    }

    // return $user_admins;

    //Return View
    return view('pages/home_admin', compact('user_admins'));
```

Still got the same error :<

### View's code:

```
@foreach ($user_admins as $admin)
 <div class="card text-center shadow-sm ml-3" style="width: 18rem;">
    <div class="card-body">
         <img src="../user_images/img_defaultprofile.png" class="mb-3" style="height: 10vh;" alt="" srcset="">
         <h5 class="card-title">{!!$admin->name!!}</h5>
         <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">{!!$admin->email!!}<h6>
         <p class="card-text">{!!$admin->desc!!}</p>
         <a href="#" class="btn btn-info">View Profile</a>
     </div>
 </div>
 @endforeach
```

Comment: `$admin` is probably an array, not an object, so you need to use array access methods, not object access methods. `$admin['name']`

Comment: @aynber I updated my question. I tried it, but still got the same error.

Comment: Show more of your view, specifically where you're defining `$admin`

Comment: @aynber I posted my view's code

Comment: You shouldn't get the same error if you use `$admin['name']` instead of `$admin->name`. Make sure you change all of the properties in your loop.

Comment: @aynber yes, I made sure all of them where changed. Still got the error.

Comment: can you show the declaration of the relationship from User to Photo? I feel you can handle this easier using the relationship and an accessor on the User model

Comment: I know it sounds weird. Use something else instead of  `$admin`. I faced the same issue recently why I try to pass '$order' to my bladeview and got the exact error. Eventhing worked out after I change `$order` to `$other names instead of order`. Not sure if it's the same case and I still try to figure out the reason. But I guess we are not in the same case most likely.

Comment: @lagbox Thanks! I used a relationship to link the User and Photo and it's now working! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle it by defining relationship between user and photo, On your user model define a relationship with photo model

```
public function photo()
{
   return $this->hasOne('App\Photo','imageable_id');
}
```

Then on your controller

```
$user_admins = User::where('role_id', $admin_id)->orderBy('name', 'asc')->get();
return view('pages/home_admin', compact('user_admins'));
```

As the relationship has been defined on user model you can retrieve the photo and user data as follows on view

```
@foreach ($user_admins as $admin)
 <div class="card text-center shadow-sm ml-3" style="width: 18rem;">
    <div class="card-body">
         <img src="{!!$admin->photo->path!!}" class="mb-3" style="height: 10vh;" alt="" srcset="">
         <h5 class="card-title">{!!$admin->name!!}</h5>
         <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">{!!$admin->email!!}<h6>
         <p class="card-text">{!!$admin->desc!!}</p>
         <a href="#" class="btn btn-info">View Profile</a>
     </div>
 </div>
 @endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

So the error message is saying `Trying to get property of non-object`. That means, you are trying to access property of a variable which is not an object but something else. You are getting this error because, the variable you are passing `$user_admins` is an array but you are trying to access it as an object.

How to access an array? This should be the your code in view:

```php
@foreach ($user_admins as $admin)
 <div class="card text-center shadow-sm ml-3" style="width: 18rem;">
    <div class="card-body">
         <img src="../user_images/img_defaultprofile.png" class="mb-3" style="height: 10vh;" alt="" srcset="">
         <h5 class="card-title">{!!$admin['name']!!}</h5>
         <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">{!!$admin['email']!!}<h6>
         <p class="card-text">{!!$admin['desc']!!}</p>
         <a href="#" class="btn btn-info">View Profile</a>
     </div>
 </div>
 @endforeach
```